# Hidden characters when comparing URL strings

Tags: php, string

I had really strange experience debugging a string comparison.
The link generated from a function ( Magento getCategoryUrl() )
but was not able to match it to its "printed" version;

I tried all possible options for string comparison, and escaping the original string. Finally, using **strpos** I identified that the problem is in the first "h" or something before it.

```
$menu_link = $this->getMenuLink($cat_id)
echo $menu_link; // https://example.com/cat_1

if($menu_link == "https://example.com/cat_1"){...}  // false
if($menu_link  === "https://example.com/cat_1"){...}  // false
if("https://example.com/cat_1" == $menu_link){...}  // false

if(strcmp( $menu_link , "https://example.com/cat_1") == 0){...}  // false
if(strcasecmp( $menu_link , "https://example.com/cat_1") == 0){...}  // false

//Sanity Check ...
if("https://example.com/cat_1" == "https://example.com/cat_1"){...}  //true..

$menu_link = "". trim($menu_link); // no effect
if($menu_link === "https://example.com/cat_1"){...}  // false

if(strpos( $menu_link , "https://example.com/cat_1") ){...} //false

// ONLY THIS WORKS ?!
if(strpos( $menu_link , "ttps://example.com/cat_1") ){...} //true
```

still clueless why this is happening.

**UPDATE**
as @u_mulder suggested I tried var_dump, it `gives string(51) ...` but with the length is not correct, there are 9 extra characters. 
I couldn't find any way to print them ..

Comment: `var_dump($menu_link)`

Comment: @u_mulder  var_dumps gives string... but with suspicious length: 
`string(51) "https://www.domain12.com/catering-services" ` there are 9 not displayed characters, if this is correct.

Comment: So, it's time to find out where these symbols come from.

Answer (score 2):

`$menu_link` at the beginning and `$meny_link` everywhere else :)

Comment: @d.raev : Can you try with `trim()` as `trim($menu_link)`;